# use papyrus to show an uml file on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, uml, modeling

I want to show an uml file generated by MoDisco with Papyrus, because UML2Tools don't work on eclipse indigo. So can anybody explain me how can I do this? Because I cannot see something, although there is an uml file.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

UML2 files are the model behind papyrus diagrams. You can import such a model into a papyrus model (importing the packages), but it is not automatically shown - you must add the elements you want to show manually.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for your answer. So is it possible to get a plugin or something like that to show directly and automatically the uml file?

Comment: Not that I know of. If you find one please inform me :-)